# About Android full disk encryption

Tags: java, android, security

I'm trying out Android full disk encryption feature now but not sure how to verify that the device is encrypted. What I've done is :

[Test 1]

- Push test.txt to /mnt/sdcard
- Do full disk encryption
- Pull the test.txt to my local

[Test 2]

- Embed test.txt into an apk as raw data
- The apk will copy test.txt to its private folder programmatically when it's launched.
- The apk has a schedule job running at background to read test.txt from its private folder then send it to a remote server where a servlet sitting to receive the data.
- Encrypt the device
- Launch the apk, and immediately lock the screen, in case the data is encrypted only when the screen is locked
- Wait for schedule job to send test.txt to the server
- Read whatever the servlet received.

However, in both cases, I was still able to see the plain text of test.txt, why it's not encrypted? And how can I verify that the data is protected?

Thanks in advance and Happy New Year!

Comment: can you pleas give some details on how did you implement full disk encryption? I need to do that and need some inputs on where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Encryption is done at kernel level, so when you read a file it is decrypted on the fly. Otherwise every app would need to call encryption/decryption functions when reading/writing files. Additionally, the SD card is usually not encrypted itself (unless you are using a GN or a similar device that uses the same partition for internal and external storage). To verify, you could take a backup with something like nandroid which takes a disk image, then open this in a binary editor and look for plain text strings. If you don't find the contents of your text file, it means the partition is encrypted.

Comment: So, can I say that, to protect some files from reading, File locker is still required even though full disk encryption is done?

Comment: I have no idea what file locker is, but it is probably not required. Private files are only readable by the application that created them, regardless of disk encryption. If you want to protect from other apps reading your files using private files is sufficient. On rooted device, of course, any app that is granted root access can ready any file. The purpose of full disk encryption is to make sure that if your device is, say, stolen the thief cannot just dump the files and read them. They would need the passphrase to decrypt them.